# Extract elements from list to create data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, survey

```
library(survey)
```

I have data such as this. I am using the survey package to produce the MEAN, SE and FREQ of each variables in the vector named vars. I am new to manipulating lists in R & would really appreciate help!

```
df <- data.frame(sex = c('F', 'M', NA, 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F'),
                 married = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                 pens = c(0, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                 weight = c(1.12, 0.55, 1.1, 0.6, 0.23, 0.23, 0.66, 0.67))
```

I run the following code to get a list with the mean, se and freq like this:

```
vars <- c("sex","married","pens")
design <- svydesign(ids=~1, data=df, weights=~weight)


myfun <- function(x){
  means <- svymean(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design, na.rm = T)
  table <- svytable(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design)
  results <- list(svymean = means, svytable = table)
  return(results)
}

lapply(vars, myfun)
```

The output looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$svymean
                     mean     SE
interaction(sex)F 0.60345 0.2067
interaction(sex)M 0.39655 0.2067

[[1]]$svytable
interaction(sex)
   F    M 
2.45 1.61 


[[2]]
[[2]]$svymean
                          mean     SE
interaction(married)0 0.089147 0.0717
interaction(married)1 0.910853 0.0717

[[2]]$svytable
interaction(married)
   0    1 
0.46 4.70 


[[3]]
[[3]]$svymean
                      mean     SE
interaction(pens)0 0.53728 0.2255
interaction(pens)1 0.46272 0.2255

[[3]]$svytable
interaction(pens)
   0    1 
2.45 2.11
```

### I want to extract/manipulate this list above to create a dataframe that looks more like this:

```
    Var                mean     SE       freq
interaction(sex)F     0.60345 0.2067    2.45
interaction(sex)M     0.39655 0.2067    1.61
interaction(married)0 0.089147 0.0717    0.46
interaction(married)1 0.910853 0.0717     4.7
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decide to change your main function so as to run lapply only once:

```
myfun <- function(x){
  form <- reformulate(sprintf('interaction(%s)', x))
  cbind(as.data.frame(svymean(form, design, na.rm = T)), freq = c(svytable(form, design)))
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(vars, myfun))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am trying to adapt this to run it without the "interaction", but I am getting an error, can you please advice? I am attempting this: myfun <- function(x){
    form <- reformulate(sprintf('(%s)', x))
    cbind(as.data.frame(svymean(form, design, na.rm = T)), freq = c(svytable(form, design)))
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(vars, myfun))

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `lapply`

```
 do.call(rbind, lapply(lapply(vars, myfun),
       function(x)  cbind(as.data.frame(x$svymean), 
          freq = unname(x$svytable))))
```

-output

```
#                           mean        SE freq.Var1 freq.Freq
#interaction(sex)F     0.60344828 0.2066829         A      2.45
#interaction(sex)M     0.39655172 0.2066829         B      1.61
#interaction(married)0 0.08914729 0.0716663         A      0.46
#interaction(married)1 0.91085271 0.0716663         B      4.70
#interaction(pens)0    0.53728070 0.2254907         A      2.45
#interaction(pens)1    0.46271930 0.2254907         B      2.11
```

Comment: This gives me an empty df: data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

Comment: @NewBee Based on your example, it is giving me a data.frame though

Comment: so strange, I keep getting an empty df

Comment: @NewBee is it on the same example or different

Comment: I am so sorry! I wiped my history and tried again, and I see the sf! Thank you so much! Is there way to run this call without the interaction component? Such as:  myfun <- function(x){
  means <- svymean(as.formula(paste0('~(', x, ')')), design, na.rm = T)
  table <- svytable(as.formula(paste0('~interaction(', x, ')')), design)
  results <- list(svymean = means, svytable = table)
  return(results)
}
do.call(rbind, lapply(lapply(vars, myfun),
       function(x)  cbind(as.data.frame(x$svymean), 
          freq = unname(x$svytable))))

Comment: @NewBee can you please post as a new question as the questioin is already accepted

Comment: will tag you as soon as I have a new post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795182/manipulate-list-object-into-data-frame Thank so much for considering!