# Manipulate list object into data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, survey

```
library(survey)
```

I have data such as this. I am using the survey package to produce the MEAN, SE and FREQ of each variables in the vector named vars. I am new to manipulating lists in R & would really appreciate help!

```
df <- data.frame(
                 married = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                 pens = c(0, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                 weight = c(1.12, 0.55, 1.1, 0.6, 0.23, 0.23, 0.66, 0.67))


vars <- c("weight","married","pens")
design <- svydesign(ids=~1, data=df, weights=~weight)

myfun <- function(x){
  means <- svymean(as.formula(paste0('~(', x, ')')), design, na.rm = T)
  table <- svytable(as.formula(paste0('~(', x, ')')), design)
  results <- list(svymean = means, svytable = table)
  return(results)
}

lapply(vars, myfun)
```

The output looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$svymean
          mean     SE
weight 0.79791 0.1177

[[1]]$svytable
weight
0.23 0.55  0.6 0.66 0.67  1.1 1.12 
0.46 0.55 0.60 0.66 0.67 1.10 1.12 


[[2]]
[[2]]$svymean
           mean     SE
married 0.91085 0.0717

[[2]]$svytable
married
   0    1 
0.46 4.70 


[[3]]
[[3]]$svymean
        mean     SE
pens 0.46272 0.2255

[[3]]$svytable
pens
   0    1 
2.45 2.11
```

### I want to extract/manipulate this list above to create a dataframe that looks more like this:

```
question    mean     SE      sum_svytable
weight      0.797   0.1177    5.16
married      0.910  0.071     5.16
```

As you can see, the sum_svytable is the **sum of the frequencies** produced in the $svytable generated list for each variable. Even though this number is the same for each variable (5.16 for all) in my example, it is not the same in my dataset.

```
sum_svytable was derived like this:  

output of myfun function for weight: 
[[1]]$svytable
weight
0.23 0.55  0.6 0.66 0.67  1.1 1.12 
0.46 0.55 0.60 0.66 0.67 1.10 1.12 

I simply summed the frequencies for each response: 
sum_svytable(for weight) = 0.46 +0.55+ 0.60+ 0.66+ 0.67+ 1.10+ 1.12
```

I don't mind how this result is arrived at, I just need it to be in a df!

Is this possible?

Comment: @akrun please see here, thank you so much!

Comment: Is it the output based on the same function.  I get `interaction`

Comment: @akrun, sorry, will fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to loop over the `list` of output from 'myfun' then extract teh components, 'svymean', create a data.frame, add the column of `sum`s from 'svytable' element, `rbind` the `list` elements and create the 'question' column from the row names

```
out <- lapply(vars, myfun)
lst1 <- lapply(out, function(x) 
      cbind(setNames(as.data.frame(x$svymean), c("mean", "SE")),
               sum_svytable = sum(x$svytable)))
out1 <- do.call(rbind, lst1)
out1$question <- row.names(out1)
row.names(out1) <- NULL
out1[c('question', 'mean', 'SE', 'sum_svytable')]
#  question      mean        SE sum_svytable
#1   weight 0.7979070 0.1177470         5.16
#2  married 0.9108527 0.0716663         5.16
#3     pens 0.4627193 0.2254907         4.56
```